# What are the proprieties of $\mathbf{M}$ in order for $\mathbf{pM}=\mathbf{e}$ to be achieved by $\mathbf{p}$ being a probability vector?

Tags: matrices

Assume that $\mathbf{M}$ is a $N\times N$ non-singular matrix with non-negative elements, where each row  sums to $N$. Assume that $\mathbf{p}$ is a probability vector, where each element is positive, smaller than 1, and the sum of all elements of $\mathbf{p}$ is one. Then, what are the properties of $\mathbf{M}$ in order for

$$\mathbf{pM}=\mathbf{e}$$

to hold, where $\mathbf{e}$ is the all-ones row vector? Note that the above holds in general, since $\mathbf{M}$ is a $N\times N$ non-singular matrix, but it is not always achieved by  probability vector $\mathbf{p}$, i.e., if $\mathbf{M}$  does not satisfy some properties then the above is achieved with $\mathbf{p}$ not being a probability vector.

I have a conjecture that $\mathbf{M}$ must be such that there exists a matrix $\hat M$ obtained as a row-permutation of $\mathbf{M}$ that has the largest elements on its main diagonal.

Comment: @nicomezi $M$ is supposed to be non-singular.

Comment: @saulspatz You are right, but I still do not get what is supposed to be known. Are we looking at properties of $\mathbf{M}$ given $\mathbf{p}$, or are we looking for some $\mathbf{p}$ with $\mathbf{M}$ being given ...

Comment: The OP claims that for any such $M$ and $p$, $M$ can be transformed by row permutations to a matrix $M'$ so that the largest elements are on the main diagonal.  Since the rows don't change, it must mean that the diagonal elements are the largest in their columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not true.  Take $$\begin{align}
p&=\begin{bmatrix}.3&.3&.4\end{bmatrix}\\
M&=\begin{bmatrix}
1.4  & 1.4  & .2\\
1.3  & 1.2  & .5\\
.475 &  .55 & 1.975\end{bmatrix}
\end{align}$$

All the conditions are fulfilled, but since the largest elements in columns $1$ and $2$ are both in row $1$, no permutation of the rows can bring them both to the diagonal.

**EDIT**

For some reason, I thought you must mean that the diagonal elements are the largest in their column, but now I see that if we swap the first and second rows, the diagonal elements are the largest in their rows.  Is that what you meant?  I'm fairly sure I could construct a counterexample for that, too.

Comment: Dear @saulspatz, the example you gave is not valid since in your $M$ each row does not sum to $N$, where $N$ is the number of rows/columns. But thanks for the effort.

Comment: @Nik Each of the rows sums to $3$.  Isn't that what s required?

Comment: I miss calculated something...yes, they sum to 3. My conjecture is wrong. Thanks a lot @saulspatz